# Java regex for Uk postcodes with spaces

Tags: java, regex, postal-code

I'm trying to create a regex matching the following patterns (with and without space):

> M1 1AA, M60 1NW, CR2 6XH, DN55 1PT, W1A 1HQ and EC1A 1BB

I'm very new at this and find it hard to create a functional regex for all the examples above.

Searching here and there I found a regex that might work for some of the patterns but I don't know how to add the condition "with or without space" for each type of postcode.

Here the regex I found on another post "^(A-PR-UWYZ [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})"

How do I add the space/no space condition? In order to match M11AA or M1 1AA.

Comment: Some of us are not familiar with UK post codes. Can you give a few examples that should NOT match? Otherwise, it looks like any combination of capital letters and digits, starting with a capital letter, should match.

Comment: In the duplicate, in the accepted answer there are links to uk post codes syntax

Answer (score 0):

You need this regex:

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ](([0-9](([0-9]|[A-HJKSTUW])?)?)|([A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9]|[ABEHMNPRVWXY])?)) ?[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$
                                                                                     ^
```

This space must be set as optional with `?` quantifier that means *0 or 1 repetition*.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eX5uW6/1)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works well!